# Force exact class on definition

Tags: c#, class, polymorphism

Let's say I have a few classes:

```
public class ParentClass
{
    <common functionality>
    ...
}

public class ChildClass : ParentClass
{
    <additional functionality>
    ...
}
```

In my code I use both objects of `ParentClass` and `ChildClass` types - sometimes I don't need the extra functions on the `ChildClass` and sometimes I do.  (There's actually a few more generations of classes involved, but let's keep it simple.)  Is there a way to make it so that if I declare an object like so:

```
public ParentClass thing;
```

that I *won't* be able to later on define `thing` as:

```
thing = new ChildClass();
```

I want the polymorphism to the degree where `ChildClass` inherits all of `ParentClass`'s functionality, but I don't want the ability to use a more specific class when defining an object.  Can I disallow this in some way?  Sure, I could make `ParentClass` abstract, but then I wouldn't be able to have objects of type `ParentClass`, and I do sometimes need them.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to ensure that would be to pass a defined factory to your code, which would then create the ParentClass and not allow other subclasses.

```
public ParentClass thing;
thing = ParentClassFactory.Build();
```

The problem is pushing the factory to your code, but it would let you control what kind of instance is set at this point.

Comment: This might work on a simpler system, but with the engine we're using, it's pretty much out of the question.  We're not even allowed to use constructors that don't follow specific guidelines (they must have two specific prescribed parameters and no more), let alone any kind of factory scenario.  As above, it relates to the XML serialization we're doing.  I think it involves reflection, but that's outside of my department.

Comment: In this case I don't really see how you could force one type only if you don't have the leeway to change the building mechanism.

Comment: Damn. I seem to recall there was some keyword, like `explicit` that would do this sort of thing, but it doesn't seem like it'll work in this case.  (I may be thinking of another language?)  Oh well.  It was mainly for bug-searching anyhow - e.g. if I change the class of an object from child to parent, I'd like to see red error marks showing me every place in code that I need to update (it works if you go the other way), but I can do it the tedious way I suppose.